# Ошибка при подключении к MS Access базе

Tags: java, access

Есть БД на Access. При попытке подключится к ней с помощью библиотеки UCanAccess:

```
Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
String url = "jdbc:ucanaccess://" + fileSrc;
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
s = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Пациенты");
```

Получаю при подключении:

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
```

Такие ошибки:

```
WARNING:External file C:\medbase\medbase.mdb does not exist
WARNING:given file does not exist: C:\medbase\medbase.mdb
WARNING:External file C:\medbase\Перенос Поиск.mdb does not exist
WARNING:given file does not exist: C:\medbase\Перенос Поиск.mdb
WARNING:unexpected token: ___________
WARNING:unexpected token: ________
WARNING:unexpected token: _______________________
WARNING:unexpected token: ______________________
WARNING:unexpected token: ____________________
WARNING:unexpected token: ____________
WARNING:unexpected token: __________________
WARNING:unexpected token: ____________________
WARNING:unexpected token: ___________
net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: unexpected token: _________DEAA914C_823A_11D2_ABBA_525400DB56E6_
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver.connect(UcanaccessDriver.java:247)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at ru.bigspawn.AccessDatabase.<init>(AccessDatabase.java:20)
    at ru.bigspawn.Main.main(Main.java:40)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: unexpected token: _________DEAA914C_823A_11D2_ABBA_525400DB56E6_
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
    at net.ucanaccess.converters.LoadJet.exec(LoadJet.java:1308)
    at net.ucanaccess.converters.LoadJet.access$0(LoadJet.java:1303)
    at net.ucanaccess.converters.LoadJet$TablesLoader.loadForeignKey(LoadJet.java:626)
    at net.ucanaccess.converters.LoadJet$TablesLoader.loadTableFKs(LoadJet.java:819)
    at net.ucanaccess.converters.LoadJet$TablesLoader.createFKs(LoadJet.java:901)
    at net.ucanaccess.converters.LoadJet$TablesLoader.loadTables(LoadJet.java:970)
    at net.ucanaccess.converters.LoadJet$TablesLoader.access$3(LoadJet.java:966)
    at net.ucanaccess.converters.LoadJet.loadDB(LoadJet.java:1361)
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver.connect(UcanaccessDriver.java:236)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: unexpected token: _________DEAA914C_823A_11D2_ABBA_525400DB56E6_
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.parseError(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserBase.unexpectedToken(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserBase.checkIsIrregularCharInIdentifier(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.checkIsSchemaObjectName(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.readNewSchemaObjectName(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.readNewDependentSchemaObjectName(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDDL.compileAlterTable(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDDL.compileAlter(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compilePart(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compileStatements(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.executeDirectStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source)
    ... 20 more
```

Если экспортировать только необходимую таблицу и подключаться к ней, ошибок нет. Но необходимо работать с полной БД.

**Дополнено**

Я убрал ссылки на несуществующие файл из БД. Результат тот же.

```
WARNING:unexpected token: ___________
WARNING:unexpected token: ________
WARNING:unexpected token: _______________________
WARNING:unexpected token: ______________________
WARNING:unexpected token: ____________________
WARNING:unexpected token: ____________
WARNING:unexpected token: __________________
WARNING:unexpected token: ____________________
WARNING:unexpected token: ___________
net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: unexpected token: _________DEAA914C_823A_11D2_ABBA_525400DB56E6_
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver.connect(UcanaccessDriver.java:247)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at ru.bigspawn.AccessDatabase.<init>(AccessDatabase.java:22)
    at ru.bigspawn.Main.main(Main.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: unexpected token: _________DEAA914C_823A_11D2_ABBA_525400DB56E6_
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
    at net.ucanaccess.converters.LoadJet.exec(LoadJet.java:1308)
    at net.ucanaccess.converters.LoadJet.access$0(LoadJet.java:1303)
    at net.ucanaccess.converters.LoadJet$TablesLoader.loadForeignKey(LoadJet.java:626)
    at net.ucanaccess.converters.LoadJet$TablesLoader.loadTableFKs(LoadJet.java:819)
    at net.ucanaccess.converters.LoadJet$TablesLoader.createFKs(LoadJet.java:901)
    at net.ucanaccess.converters.LoadJet$TablesLoader.loadTables(LoadJet.java:970)
    at net.ucanaccess.converters.LoadJet$TablesLoader.access$3(LoadJet.java:966)
    at net.ucanaccess.converters.LoadJet.loadDB(LoadJet.java:1361)
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver.connect(UcanaccessDriver.java:236)
    ... 9 more
    Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: unexpected token: _________DEAA914C_823A_11D2_ABBA_525400DB56E6_
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.parseError(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserBase.unexpectedToken(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserBase.checkIsIrregularCharInIdentifier(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.checkIsSchemaObjectName(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.readNewSchemaObjectName(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.readNewDependentSchemaObjectName(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDDL.compileAlterTable(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDDL.compileAlter(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compilePart(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compileStatements(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.executeDirectStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source)
    ... 20 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Положите бд Access в каталог в названии которого нет пробелов и используются только символы латиницы из набора ASCII.

Это известные грабли с кириллицей.

Comment: Он же в первых четырёх строках пишет что не может найти файлы базы данных...

Comment: Увы, это не помогло.

Comment: Путь к БД `fileSrc ="C:\\Users\\bigspawn\\Desktop\\SyncAccessDB\\System_full.mdb"`. А экспортированная таблица лежит там же и таких ошибок нет.

Comment: @bigspawn, Но ведь это не соответствует рекомендации: **WARNING:External file C:\medbase\Перенос Поиск.mdb does not exist**

Comment: Убедитесь, что имена файлов точно соответствуют, лучше не набивать их вручную, а скопи-пастить из проводника, возможно где-то вместо "видищейся" вам латинской буквы на самом деле стоит русская. Ещё лучше самому переименовать файлы латинскими буквами, что бы быть уверенным, и попробовать их... Что возвращает метод [java.io.File.exists()] (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#exists%28%29)?

Comment: Игорь, не ерепенься и делай как говорят старшие товарищи :)